# How can I kill a child process run by exec on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, child-process, kill-process

I must use the method `exec` on Nodejs because I need to do some stdout redirections and run more than one command at the same time. So I run the child process like this:

```javascript
let shell = null;
const child_process = require('child_process')
var command = 'activate python_environment & bokeh serve project_folder/ log/logger.log 2>&1';
shell = child_process.exec(command);
```

I need [ps-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-tree) to kill the children as I do in the belower code. It works well on Ubuntu. But the problem is that I get an orphan (zombie) process on Windows if I do not kill the children processes.

```javascript
const psTree = require('ps-tree')
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    electron.app.quit()
    if(shell != null){
        psTree(shell.pid, function (err, children) {
            children.map(function (p) {
                process.kill(p.PID);                    
            });
        });
    }
});
```

The `ps-tree` module uses the command `ps` on linux and the command `wmic` on Windows. So it is crossplatform. But it does not work in my case. Is there a better way to do this?

I was exploring in the `ps-tree` source code but I found nothing.

I use `process.kill` because I am using [electron](https://electron.atom.io/) as well.

I am afraid I should try to do it manually getting all the processes list with `wmic`. That is what `ps-tree` is trying to do.

Note: The module [`tree-kill`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-kill) did not work on both platforms neither.

**Update**

Well, I found an ugly workaround. I save my python process PID into an external file through python code `os.getpid()`. With this I can access to the problematic PID within node like this:

```javascript
const fs = require('fs'); 
fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
    process.kill(parseInt(data, 10));
    app.quit();                
});
```

Comment: Looks dangerous - process IDs get reused, so you could be killing random processes that just happened to have a parent with the same process ID as your shell.  The most robust way to deal with a process tree is to use a job object.  If `node.js` doesn't have support for that, you could write a C program to run the child command on your behalf.

Comment: What do you mean by "job object"? What I want to do is to kill the shell process and its children, I want to kill the complete tree. After that, other processes can reuse the process IDs

Comment: You can use a job object to track a process tree, it can also be used to kill all the processes.  [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE)  Not straightforward, unfortunately. The risk in using `ps-tree` is that the process ID of the shell process might have previously belonged to some other process.  You'll kill all of the children of that process as well as the ones in your process tree.  I guess if you can identify them by some other characteristic in addition to the parent PID, you could filter the results accordingly.

Comment: ... one of the other problems with using the parent PID is that if the shell launches process A, which launches process B, and then A exits, you've got no way to identify B.  Its parent process is A, not the shell, and A is already gone so you can't even do a recursive search.  (That might be why `ps-tree` isn't working for you, perhaps?)

Comment: I think `ps-tree` should kill first the children and, after that, the parents, recursively. So it should get a list of all process PIDs and then kill them all

Comment: Perhaps it does, I don't know.  But if process A has *already* exited before you called `ps-tree` then the necessary information no longer exists.  (Typically in this sort of scenario A exits immediately after launching B.  It might already be gone by the time the call to `.exec()` returns.)

Comment: ... I've just seen your latest edit and it looks like I misunderstood your scenario.   Since you're in control of creating the child/grandchild process, a job object would be horrific overkill. :-)  Your proposed workaround sounds OK.  It would probably be possible to make it all a bit more elegant and a trifle more robust with a wrapper program, but probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts!! I think the workaround is enough for now :)

Answer (score 2):

I answer for Windows because that's the one you have troubles with.

Looking at the command you execute it seems to me your concatenation of two commands could be the culprit, so I would try doing without it.

If you can't using wmic is the best way I know of, the first time you will have to check manually yes. Once you have the select criterium you can close everything automaticly.
While the processes are busy run the command `wmic process>processes.txt`
After that using an editor check the file processes.txt and look in the column `commandline` for a common string for all the processes you want to kill.
This will be your select criterium.
Since the whole command line that created the process is there with path and parameters this should be no problem.

After that you should be able to close all those processes with the command

```
wmic process Where "CommandLine Like '%my_select_criterium%'" Call Terminate
```

I use this technique in a Ruby script that calls a bad behaving java app that I have no controll over.

Comment: This does not address the OP's specific problem at all? This only provides the API for using the wmic command (which `ps-tree` is already doing)

Comment: @AP, since the ps-tree isn't working like supposed I answer his question Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can at least attempt to wrap this into a node specific answer, by showing how you can do this using [***`spawnSync()`***](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options)  or  [***`execSync()`***](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options). So it's relevant as an answer.

Comment: OP shows he has no problem with that since he uses this technique in his question ´var command = ...´ In any way he would have to test it first manually in the CMD shell, Since I don't use node feel free to take my command line and make it a node answer.

Comment: I tried to run `wmic` with `spawn` but I cannot get the answer with stdout as the documentation says. So I keep looking for the solution. Thanks

Comment: and with spawnSync() or execSync() like AP suggests ?
Anyway, after running the wmic Call Terminate command and after some testing you can presume that these processes are effectively killed, so why do you need to get response ?

Comment: Because first I need to get a list of PID because I need to do it recursively with all the children and grandchildren. I think wmic is not able to do that

Comment: I think it does, that is just the point of my answer, no need for pid's, have you tried what I suggested ? No common string in the command line ?